# Get File Names from Web directory - from Services

Tags: c#, wcf, filenames

Could you please let me know how can i fetch the file names from a web directory at a service level. I have a wrapper services. Inside it I am trying to fetch file names. I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: What have you done already?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, which I may not since you werent too specific, sounds as easy as getting FTP listing:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```